# Mongoose query with await returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

Following code is written in a loop in a express route handler;

```
const projects = await Projects.find({});//working fine
for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    const project = projects[i];
    const build = await Build.find({ id: project.latest_build});
    //logger.debug(build[0].status); //error
    const features = await Feature.find({ build_id: project.latest_build});
    logger.debug(features[0].status);

}
```

The above code gives error at liine 4.

```
(node:672375) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

However, It is correctly printed in the logs. Seems like the value of the variable is being filled by a promise lazily.

But Line number 6 always works fine.

Note: I'm not performing any other read/write operations on above collections.

**Update**

- `id` is unique key for `Build` collection.
- `build_id` is normal field for `Feature` collection.

Schemas and Documents are created like this

```
Schemas.Projects =  new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    title: String,
    latest_build: String
});
Schemas.Build =  new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    run_date: Date,
    status: String,
});

Schemas.Feature =  new mongoose.Schema({
    id : String,
    build_id: String,
    summary : String,
    status: String,
    flows: Number,
});

const Projects = mongoose.model('Projects', Schemas.Projects);
const Build = mongoose.model(`Build_${projId}`, Schemas.Build);
const Feature = mongoose.model(`Feature_${projId}`, Schemas.Feature);
```

Comment: >  Seems like the value of the variable is being filled by a promise lazily. - no it's not. Can you try to execute the same query in mongo directly? How is Build model defined?

Comment: working fine in mongo. `id` is unique key in `Build` model. I've updated the question for the same.

Comment: Line 2 logs the correct value and even then throws an error?

Comment: @raina77ow I've updated the question with `Build` schema. Is this you're asking for? `logger.debug(build)` prints `[
  {
    _id: 60e048a6d62e4f2c71363796,
    id: '1',
    run_date: 2021-07-03T11:23:18.934Z,
    status: 'passed',
    __v: 0
  }
]`

Comment: @TusharShahi Yes. Even this code logs correctly but gives error `Build.find({ id: project.latest_build}, (err,docs) => {
    logger.debug(docs[0].status);
});`

Comment: Could you add Feature definition to the question?

Comment: And one (I hope) final addition - how actual _models_ (Build and Feature are models, right?) are created based on these schemas.

Comment: @raina77ow done. Sorry I'm not sure what piece of code could help. So adding in chunks :)

Comment: That's weird indeed. Which version of Mongoose is used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234477/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-amit-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code in question is that it was overly optimistic in its expectations. This line...

```
const build = await Build.find({ id: project.latest_build });
logger.debug(build[0].status)
```

... assumed the query always finds at least one Build document. But, as the code was running as a part of the loop, the results were actually mixed:

- at the first iteration, the query did find the Build object by the first project's data, and correctly logged its status
- at the second iteration it gave back an empty array instead. Then the code threw an Error on attempting to access `status` property of `build[0]` (which was undefined).

---

The appropriate solution for this issue depends on how you should treat those cases. If each Project **must** have a corresponding Build (it's a strictly 1-1 relation), then having an Error thrown at you is actually fine, as you just have to fix it.

Still, it might be worth treating it as a 'known error', like this:

```
const buildId = project.latest_build;
const builds = await Build.find({ id: buildId });
if (!builds.length) {
  logger.error(`No build found for ${buildId}`);
  continue;
}
```

In this case (assuming logger is set up correctly) you won't have your code blowing up, yet the error will be logged. But if it's actually an ok situation to have no builds yet, just drop the logging - and treat this case as a *known* edge case.